# Targeting the uploaded file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to get an xml file from the user via upload button and than parse it. Here are my codes for doing it -

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var xml = evt.target.files[0];
  console.log(xml);
  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    $title = $xml.find("title");
  console.log($title.text());
}

$("#file").change(handleFileSelect);

$("#upload").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($("#file").val() == "") {
    alert("Select a xml file for upload!");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Upload xml ...</h2>
<input type="file" id="file" accept=".xml" />
<button id="upload">Upload it</button>
<div id="xml-data"></div>
```

I was testing my code with this xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Awmds>
    <General_segment>
    <title>Just a title</title>
   </General_segment>
</Awmds>
```

I have tried to log the value of the **title** attribute of the xml file in the console and it has returned an empty string.

It seems i am failing to target the uploaded file correctly. How can i solve this problem ?

Here is the live jsFiddle of the code - https://jsfiddle.net/ni8mr/6kd6h6v4/4/

Comment: You need to write some back-end code to deal with the file upload if that's what you want to do. Note though that if you simply want to parse the file you can do that on the client using a FileReader. See MDN form more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: I just want to parse the file in the client-side and than i will make json based on parsed data. Thanks for referring to FileReader. I am going to try that.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting FileReader API. The job is done - https://jsfiddle.net/ni8mr/6kd6h6v4/9/